ошибка"Unable to connect to localhost"
я прохожу курс по С++ и на уроке на котором обьясняли как подключить mysql через mysql-connector к C++ при запуске программы мне выдало ошибку "Unable to connect to localhost"
Версия MySQL 8.3.0

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

using namespace std;

const string SERVER = "tcp://localhost:3306";
const string USER = "root";
const string PASSWORD = "root";

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");
    sql::Driver* driver;
    sql::Connection* conn = nullptr;
    sql::Statement* stmt;

    try {
        driver = get_driver_instance(); //делает ссылку на sql коннектор c++
        conn = driver->connect(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD);
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException& ex) {
        if (conn != nullptr && !conn->isClosed())
            conn->close();
        cout << "Error connection.\n" << ex.what();
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    conn->close();
    return 0;
}



Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Начать стоит с логичного вопроса - сервер-то запущен хоть?

Почитайте тут, возможно там перечислена одна из проблем.
